# ssh-copy-id without authentication

Tags: ssh, security

How does Linux server allow anyone to copy the string (public key) using ssh-copy-id without authentication? Doesn't it allow the unknown user to copy any malicious file onto the server?

Comment: What gave you that impression? `ssh-copy-id` just automates the commands `scp .ssh/id_rsa.pub user@other-host; ssh user@other-host 'cat id_rsa.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys`, i.e. it's just a convenience script. It _does_ require authentication.

Comment: @PerlDuck So, can  anyone who knows the server's public ip create public key and copy that onto the server ?

Comment: @Prem No. You need the password of `user@other-host` to add the public key to `user@other-host`'s authorized_keys file. Believe me: `ssh-copy-id` doesn't do anything else than `scp` and `ssh` _on your behalf_.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`ssh-copy-id` just automates the commands

```
scp .ssh/id_rsa.pub user@other-host:
ssh user@other-host 'cat id_rsa.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
ssh user@other-host 'rm id_rsa.pub'
```

That is: it copies your local `id_rsa.pub` file to the other server and appends it to the remote user's `authorized_keys` file.

It is just a convenience script and it *requires* authentication. You have to supply `user`'s password (at `other-host`) for it to work. `ssh-copy-id` doesn't do anything else than `scp` and `ssh` *on your behalf* so if they require password authentication, `ssh-copy-id` will do so as well.

Answer (score 4):

If they don't know the password, they can't copy the id into the server so don't turn off PasswordAuthentication.

```
Match User user1,user2,user3
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

**Edit** :

If you allow login without auth, they don't even need to copy-id their key, since they can login anyway without the key, IF they know the username..

Comment: And if they know the password ?

Comment: PasswordAuthentication weakens the security to the strength of the passwords. If you use public key only, you don't have any dumb passwords making it guessable, because every password is not accepted, no matter what.